# I lost session in PHP

Tags: php, html, session, session-variables

I have a problem about session in PHP. I lost the session information that I set. "header" redirects to index.php again but array of session turns back empty again after redirect. I tried using "exit();" after header but it didn't work. Thank you for your help from now.

my index.php :

```
<?php 
session_start();
ob_start();
print_r($_SESSION);

?>

<a href="/uu/test.php"> sign in </a>
```

test.php :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['username'])){

    $usr= $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['usr']= $usr;
    header('Location:/uu');

}

?>
<form action="" method="post">

Username: <br>
<input type="text" name="username"> <br>
Password: <br>
<input type="Password" name="password"> <br>
<button type="submit">Sign In</button>

</form>
```

Comment: You appear to  be missing `session_start` in test.php.

Comment: This already sounds unsafe. I hope you're using a safe hashing password method later on; one such as `password_hash()`, along with a prepared statement.

Comment: @JonStirling I thought, I started session in index.php and that's all. Thank you for your answer. Appreciate it!

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thank you for your answer! I will consider it!

Comment: you're welcome. Stay safe.